# Setting up second nic on Ubuntu for Virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox-networking

I am very much a beginner in the networking realm.  I have a server running Ubuntu that has 2 nics.  eth0 was the primary and now I am wanting to setup a VM as a webserver and use the second nic to pipe 80 traffic to the VM only.  I thought it would be as easy as plugging a cord into the 2nd nic, setting up a static ip on my router to that nic's mac address, and setting a bridged connection on the guest VM settings in virtual box to that new nic.  Alas, simple never seems to work...
So, how would I go about setting this up?  Below is the output of several calls. I have no idea why the second nic is "tun0" and not eth1, no idea what "tun0" even means (tunnel...? did not setup anything to tunnel).  any help is greatly appreciated!

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:4a:00:03:ce:07  
          inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c24a:ff:fe03:ce07/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:127281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19873825 (19.8 MB)  TX bytes:24075843 (24.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14960 (14.9 KB)  TX bytes:14960 (14.9 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: `tun0` is definitely not your second card, apparently `eth1` is not configured at all.